# jQuery - TimeAgo Highlight Numbers

Tags: jquery, timeago

I am using TimeAgo jQuery plugin.

How can I highlight only numbers in TimeAgo `<abbr>` tag?

### **Format should look like**

[image]

---

### [Online Demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/gu5yayfm)

---

> **HTML**

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
```

> **jQuery**

```
$("abbr.timeago").timeago();
```

> **CSS**

```
abbr span{font-weight:bold;color:red;}
```

Comment: You might need to edit plugin and separate `number` and `text` into different container or else some serious `jquery` will do

Comment: Yes i guess you should modify the jquery plugin yourself to make this functionality . there is no other way i suppose

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue/wish for those who need the solution here it is:

if you open the jquery.timeago.js 
there is a section strings:

```
 strings: {
    prefixAgo: null,
    prefixFromNow: null,
    suffixAgo: "geleden",
    suffixFromNow: "vanaf nu",
    inPast: 'elk moment',
    seconds: "minder dan een minuut",
    minute: "ongeveer een minuut",
    minutes: "<b>%d</b> minuten",
    hour: "ongeveer een uur",
    hours: "ongeveer <b>%d</b> uren",
    day: "een dag",
    days: "<b>%d</b> dagen",
    month: "ongeveer een maand",
    months: "<b>%d</b> maanden",
    year: "ongeveer een jaar",
    years: "<b>%d</b> jaren",
    wordSeparator: " ",
    numbers: []
  }
```

in this case I've translated it to dutch and made it bold, you could jut use a span and style it.

```
time.timeago > span{ color:red;}
```

last point to change is change the following line (194)

```
From:
$(this).text(inWords(data.datetime));
To:
$(this).html(inWords(data.datetime));
```

hope this helps.